# A query with regard to removing data from a dataset before clustering. - conceptual

Tags: clustering, dimensionality-reduction

I am in posession of data with regard to my domain which is energy economics. The dataset contains daily data on daily electricity demand along with the daily capacities of wind and solar plants for 365 days for multiple locations. I am aware that there are extreme days where you have high demand or high solar/wind capacity and these would affect clustering with the samples almost behaving like outliers. But my dataset is also high dimensional so I need to reduce the dimensions before performing clustering to identify what are called representative days in the 365 sample dataset. In such a situation is it adivisable to remove the extreme days, perform dimensional reduction and then clustering as when dimensional reduction is performed, the dynamics within the dataset would not be properly captured and this incomplete reduced data ( I will use a dimensional reduction technique like dynamic PCA which captures dynamics of the data as well) would then be subjected to clustering ?